# How angularJS update $scope data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a code like this:

```
$http.post('/getUserInfo', Obj)

            .then(function(response) {
                //console.log(response.data);
                $scope.items = response.data;
            });
```

The data received in the response is set to **$scope.items**. If i run this code once again, will it change the whole **$scope.items** or it will only watch the change between the new and the old values of **$scope.items** ?

*Assume that **response.data** contains huge amount of data.*

Comment: Yes,  it will change the whole `$scope.items`

Comment: How can i override this thing ? Any idea..

Comment: Why do you use `post` to get the data? try using get and cache your response

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are concerned because you're iterating over the data with `ng-repeat`, what you need to do is use `track by` in the `ng-repeat` parameter to specify some condition that will tell angular that a particular element is unchanged. Then it will match that element up with the element from the old array and avoid reconstructing the html for the element.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by item.uniqueid">
   ... content here ...
</div>
```

and make sure that the `uniqueid` attribute remains the same when the data remains the same but changes if the content of an element is updated. You might for example combine an id for the user with the date and time of the last update to provide a suitably unique value.